# Can Python Print Bits

Tags: python, printing, byte, bit

From what I can tell,the random function is returning bits.  So why is type(key) giving me "string"? And if it is a string, or if its bits, how come I cannot print it out? If I print it out it gives nonesense characters that the computer cannot read.

```
def random(size=16):
  return open("/dev/urandom").read(size)

key = random()
print type(key)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, a stream of bytes (or bits) is represented as a string. The nonsense characters that are printed out are a result of the fact that not all combinations of bits map to valid characters in the ASCII encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

If you want to see the random bits as 1s and 0s, you can convert each character to a number using `ord` and then format the number as binary:

```
s = random()
print "".join(map("{0:08b}".format, map(ord, list(s))))  # 8 bits per byte
```

If you're trying to generate random numbers, why not use the [random module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how python works with bits and string :)

**code**

```
    def __String_to_BitList(data):
    """Turn the string data, into a list of bits (1, 0)'s"""
    if _pythonMajorVersion < 3:
        # Turn the strings into integers. Python 3 uses a bytes
        # class, which already has this behaviour.
        data = [ord(c) for c in data]
    l = len(data) * 8
    result = [0] * l
    pos = 0
    for ch in data:
        i = 7
        while i >= 0:
            if ch & (1 << i) != 0:
                result[pos] = 1
            else:
                result[pos] = 0
            pos += 1
            i -= 1

    return result

def __BitList_to_String(data):
    """Turn the list of bits -> data, into a string"""
    result = []
    pos = 0
    c = 0
    while pos < len(data):
        c += data[pos] << (7 - (pos % 8))
        if (pos % 8) == 7:
            result.append(c)
            c = 0
        pos += 1

    if _pythonMajorVersion < 3:
        return ''.join([ chr(c) for c in result ])
    else:
        return bytes(result)
```